# Unsure how to assign monadic value to Aeson pair

Tags: haskell, aeson

Consider the following code:

```
    S.get "/budget/:bid/month/:mnth" $ do
      mbid <- param "bid"
      (budget :: Maybe Budget) <- liftIO $ getBudget $ toSqlKey mbid
      (categories :: [Entity Category]) <- liftIO $ getCategories $ toSqlKey mbid
      case budget of 
        Nothing -> json $ object [ "message" .= ("No budget was found!" :: String) ]
        Just b -> do
          json $ object [
              "categoryExpenditures" .= map (\x -> object ["spent" .= liftIO $ 
                calculateCategoryBalanceForMonth (entityKey x) 1 >>= (\y -> y) ]) categories
            ]
```

Up until this point, `calculateCategoryBalanceForMonth` has type `calculateCategoryBalanceForMonth :: CategoryId -> Int -> IO Double`.

I am attempting to map over `categories` and return a list of `categoryExpenditures` as a JSON object in Aeson. However, I cannot figure out how to return the value from `liftIO` to the `.=` operator.

My attempt involved desugaring the assignment operator to `>>= (\y -> y)` or `>>= id` where I was hoping `id` would return a Double, or at least something that had an instance of `ToJSON`. This does not appear to be the case though.

I also know that using the assignment operator for the `liftIO` expression, and then passing the assigned variable into the `.=` operator works, however I was unsure how to use the assignment operator within an anonymous function for map.

What might I be doing wrong? Is any more clarity needed?

Comment: Could you please post a self contained code snippets or at least some signatures? It is impossible to read haskell without signatures at hand. And as far as I can see you're trying to do IO during conversion to JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with a monad stack with `IO` at the bottom.

`object` takes `[Pair]` as argument, however you're trying to pass it an `IO`. `(>>=)` keeps things *inside* the monad (by definition!), so `(>>= id)` does not do what you want it to (in fact, the signature of `(>>= id)` is `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, ergo `join`). You want to move things around a bit:

```
Just b -> do
      expenditures <- forM categories (\x -> do
          spent <- liftIO $ calculateCategoryBalanceForMonth (entityKey x) 1
          return $ object [ "spent" .= spent ])
      json $ object [ "categoryExpenditures" .= expenditures ]
```

For mapping with a monadic result, use `mapM`, or `forM` (`forM = flip mapM`).